# How to change the background of the ActionBar?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-actionbar

Already followed several tutorials on the subject and as I am beginner'm still the problem.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.universo91.towersrock" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Utils.ApplicationClass"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".Pages.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/noticias_menu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Pages.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
          <!-- <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>-->
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see in the manifest I sit logo and icon, but it also will not appear on ActionBar. How can I resolve?

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/excursoes_button"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/excursoes_button"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Just stick to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Comment: @JJD tried that and it does not work.

Comment: Which **version of Android** are you running and what exactly did you try?

Comment: @JJD how can I see the version? In manifest not show the version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The official documentation didn't work in the version I was working.
This code worked for me

```
public void setActionBar(String heading) {

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.title_bar_gray)));
    actionBar.setTitle(heading);
    actionBar.show();

}
```

in values/strings.xml add the following line

```
<color name="title_bar_gray">#2E9AFE</color>
```

Then you just call the method on onCreate()

Comment: Veto. `onCreate()` is part of the [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). These methods are **not** supposed to be called manually!